# Python- Creating a tuple from a txt file

Tags: python, file, text, tuples

I am currently trying to take out information from a text file and store it in a tuple. So at the moment the text file looks like this:

```
name age height weight
name age height weight
```

and so on

I want to take them out and store them in separate tuples, such as name tuple, age tuple, height tuple. But I am getting "`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)`"

I know how to get it in a list with the code I have now

```
file1 = open(input (str("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" )),"r")
name, age, height, weight = zip(*[l.split() for l in file1.readlines()])
```

need some help thanks guys

im using python 3.4

Answer (score 4):

You can use `zip` and comprehension like this

```
text_file = open("Input.txt", "r")
name, age, height, weight = zip(*[l.split() for l in text_file.readlines()])
```

Its always good to use `with`, when you are dealing with files

```
with open("Input.txt", "r") as text_file:
    name, age, height, weight = zip(*[l.split() for l in text_file.readlines()])
```

**Sample Run:**

```
~/Desktop$ python3 Test.py
Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:Input.txt
('alex',) ('17',) ('170',) ('6.4',)
~/Desktop$
```

Comment: @JonClements Fixed it Jon :)

Comment: Can you explain what the * is doing in zip?

Comment: @rgk It unpacks the values from the generated list and passes all of them as parameters to `zip` function.

Comment: @thefourtheye - Thank you. Just read the official documentation - zip() in conjunction with the * operator can be used to unzip a list. This will help me reduce a lot of for loops.

Comment: is there a reason why i am getting a syntax error for both the text_file and with open suggestions. thanks for the help and the quick replys

Comment: @user3077551 Could you please update the question with the latest code which you are using?

Comment: its just a syntax error on your suggestion. the "text_file" and the "with open" are throwing them up. is there a reason for this.

Comment: @user3077551 Sorry. I couldnt guess without looking at the actual code.

Comment: @user3077551 are you definitely using `3.4` and not `2.4`? :) (as your print statements wouldn't work) and the `with` statement was not in `2.4` etc... so - just wondering :)

Comment: i have updated to code and i am getting the user to input there file name. the code is throwing up "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

Comment: @user3077551 The code is working fine for me. I dont see any big mistakes in that code. Could you please show the complete error messages as well?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LON-PC3024\Documents\ass2 task 1\ass2 task 2.py", line 3, in <module>
    name, age, height, weight = zip(*[l.split() for l in file1.readlines()])
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Comment: @user3077551 It could be because of the fact that the input data in the file is not in the format you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @user3077551 Please have a look at the sample run included in the answer, for the input you provided

Comment: hahah one more question. how would i search through the tuples so if the user input a character say alex, it would display everything about him, ie wieght hight and age

Comment: @user3077551 That would be a separate question I believe :) Please consider accepting this answer, if it helps you :)